# The best way to store almost the same 4 fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, search, database-design, architecture

i need to store something like this:

```
mac_1 string
mac_2 string
mac_3 string
mac_4 string
```

With the ability to search record by 4 macs(or 1 mac). Iterate each record and value will be not the best option? MySQL MATCH AGAINST will have heavy load on server. I can't use fulltext search :( Can you please suggest an easy and elegant way for storing such kind of data?

Comment: Why dont you store the common part "mac_" in a master table and the autoincremental value 1,2,3 will be appended while the select

Comment: What do you mean by "search"? Equi-search, prefix, infix, suffix? I'm guessing equi, please confirm. Also, what does it mean to search "by 4 macs": do you mean AND or OR?

Comment: I mean Equi-search using AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an efficient equi-search, it is enough to index all 4 fields.

The question is whether you can use one composite index that covers all 4 fields, or 4 separate indexes:

- If you have a predominant "leading edge" on which you (almost) always search, then just create a composite index with that leading edge. For example, if you always search on `mac_1` whether you search on other fields or not, just create a composite index on `{mac_1, ...}`. Since you are using AND condition, this index will enable you to find the row in a single index seek.
- If you have many variations of the leading edge, just create separate indexes on all fields. This will require up to 4 index seeks, but should still be fairly fast.

Just be aware that [InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) and the "seek" on the *secondary* index of a clustered table may actually require 2 seeks (the index seek itself + primary/clustering index seek). You can avoid that through [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index), but possibly at the price of increased storage and decreased caching efficiency.

Also be careful [not to be too clever](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic) when constructing your query, so the optimizer can actually utilize these indexes. Don't shy away from dynamic SQL if needed.

---

The alternative design would be to have two tables connected by a foreign key, where "child" table would contain the `mac` values....

```
CREATE TABLE p (
    p_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    -- Other fields...
);

CREATE TABLE c (
    p_id INT REFERENCES p (p_id),
    mac varchar(50), -- Or whatever type is appropriate.
    PRIMARY KEY (p_id, mac)
);
```

...and then query for parent rows that are connected to the `mac` value of (for example)  `'aaa' AND 'bbb' AND 'ccc'` like this:

```
SELECT p.p_id -- Other fields...
FROM p JOIN c ON p.p_id = c.p_id
WHERE mac = 'aaa' OR mac = 'bbb' OR mac = 'ccc'
GROUP BY p.p_id -- Other fields...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79915/1)

BTW, this design would allow for more than 4 `mac` values per parent row if necessary.

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have the most sophisticated query optimizer out there, so please test on realistic amounts of data before committing to this design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i learn a lot of new stuff from it :)!

Answer (score 1):

You should split this field into its constituents and store them in slave table. This will have following benefits:

- No artificial limit of 4 macs per row. It can be 0, it can be 10, but you can limit it at insert time
- If you index slave table properly, search will be fast

Comment: Well, this will be dead easy, but data is completely unrelated to any entity in app.

Comment: well, your entity is parent row as it is right now. you must have unique id in parent table, just link your slave table to this parent id.

Answer (score 1):

Why not store the concatenation of all fields as another field:

```
mac_1 string
mac_2 string
mac_3 string
mac_4 string
mac_full string
```

Comment: MACs can be in various order in search term